# I cannot install Kubuntu, it keeps rebooting before installation

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, reboot

I installed Ubuntu on my computer with no problem. I didn't like it so I wiped the drive and tried to install Kubuntu. It will boot from either CD or usb drive up until I have a choice to try it or install it. If i hit install it will think for a second and then just reboot. If i try it, it works fine and I can take the tour. But once I click install from there, it reboots also. Ive tried installing it from windows. I burnt an ISO of the disc,  ran that and it opens wubi and then downloads the iso again... whats going on there?
My system is a new 3.9ghz AMD APU 64bit processor on a MSI mb. 8 gigs of ram.
Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two or three possible causes for this to happen.

**1. APCI or APM-related issues**

Try setting nomodeset and nolapic/noapic and acpi=off boot parameters ([Description on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52096/what-do-the-different-boot-options-mean-i-e-acpi-off-noapic-nolapic-etc)). It might turn out your bios isn't implementing some interfaces correctly.

**2. Make sure your RAM is fine**

Combination or missarangement of RAM modules or defect modules may also cause this error. Do a memory check (3rd option on boot screen).

**3. Alternate install disk**

If you still have no luck, try the alternate installation disk. You will have no GUI guiding the install, but instead have a text based menu. You can find the [images here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/).