# Hades Canyon NUC8i7HVK can install but can't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, nomodeset

Just got my new Intel NUC today. It installs just fine, but booting up it gets stuck forever with no error message (black screen).

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you provide more details?. Press the `Esc` key to see where the boot process stoped, and post the line in here so we can help you in a better way.

Comment: Pressing the `Esc` key doesn't make a difference. Screen is black and completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go into the GRUB menu and select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.
2. We will edit the startup options, so press `e`.
3. On the end of the line starting with `linux     /boot`  add a word: `nomodeset`

[image]

I have no idea why this works but it does. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: IDK if it will work in this case, but what it does is bypass the graphics drivers.

Comment: you can find the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean

Comment: To set `nomodeset` permanently do https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782

Comment: @Mika: Also trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from usb/live-cd on the hades canyon. When selection option 1 (try ubuntu without installing) it gets stuck in a black screen, even if adding nomodeset. When selecting option 2 (install Ubuntu) it also gets stuck, even if adding nomodeset. Did you do anything else ( bios setting? ) to get it to install?

Comment: Update: My Hades Canyon originally came with FW 0029. First FW revision mentioned in the Intel-docs (Initial Pre-production FW) is 0034... After upgrading to latest (currently 0037) and using the nomodeset-parameter it boots into Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes @kalmiya, I had previously upgraded firmware. It seemed like the smart first thing to do. Guess I was spot on

Comment: Can anyone explain why it *doesn't* work for me? (HNK model, upgraded to BIOS 44 from 29). If I take off "quiet" it says "Loading initial ramdisk" when it hangs.