# Ubuntu 18.04: enabling the AMD Vega (Radeon RX Vega M) drivers on Intel NUC8I7HVK (Hades Canyon)

Tags: amd-graphics

There are several posts in various forums by people who claim to have solved the problem of Ubuntu 18.04 not supporting the AMD Vega graphics card:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400400
- [Cannot Install 18.04.1 on Intel 8th Gen NUC (8i7HVK)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064222/cannot-install-18-04-1-on-intel-8th-gen-nuc-8i7hvk)
- [Graphics drivers for Intel NUC Hades Canyon NUC8i7HVK (AMD Radeon RX Vega GH)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040440/graphics-drivers-for-intel-nuc-hades-canyon-nuc8i7hvk-amd-radeon-rx-vega-gh)

However, no matter which kernel version I install, the AMD drivers are not activated and I get only software OpenGL renderer:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon RX Vega M]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: modesetting,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 3840x2160@88.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2
```

Is there some way to diagnose what's going on? Ie, check if the required drivers are in the current kernel (maybe my specific version does not contain the vega m patches), or see if the system tried to load those drivers and failed.