# ACPI Error when I tried to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, bios, acpi, usb-installation

```
[0.246967] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PB2], 
AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)

[0.246979] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND. During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)

[0.911667] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

- ubuntu version Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- BIOS UPDATED
- Flash usb formated
- Device - lenovo legion 7

[image]

Comment: it happens when i press "try or install ubuntu"

Comment: notices shown during boot are not an issue. if boot stops it is the NEXT one not shown, and then it is basically almost the video card driver.  add `nomodeset` at grub as a boot parameter and see if it then continues.   (reference https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean )

Comment: The acpi notices started appearing with kernel 5.19 and that was due a decision by the kernel developers to stop hiding bios notifications. We users can't fix them, You can suppress them if you want (the `quiet` kernel parameters has a `errorlevel=`  vith a number that removes most or all messages during boot (number 2 remove acpi warnings)