# How GRUB setting noapic affects the system?

Tags: 11.04, grub2

What are the known issues when setting GRUB to boot with **noapic**? How does the setting affect the system or programs in it?

[This quick answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52096/what-do-the-different-boot-options-mean-i-e-acpi-off-noapic-nolapic-etc) explains what **noapic** does, but is there some example situations?

This question is connected to this problem: [Unable to install/boot 11.04 on a ThinkPad L520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51983/unable-to-install-boot-11-04-on-a-thinkpad-l520).

Answer (score 2):

Varies from system-to-system.  Some reports of USB issues have been made.

Have you tried booting with `apic=debug` and posting the logs and `dmesg` output etc?

Upgrading the BIOS might provide a fix to the issue that causes apic to fail for you too.

Answer (score 2):

FYI on this (Thinkpad/Ubuntu) I have found that using "noapic" on Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) on a Lenovo Thinkpad L420 (Intel Core-i5-2520M) is the only way to get suspend/hibernate/shutdown working in all ways (FN buttons or pm-suspend, etc.). Works perfectly (so far) with VirtualBox running. I haven't noticed degradation yet. I would be nice for a detailed explanation of "noapic" :).