# Updating Bios and Ubuntu 11.10.. seem like they don't mix

Tags: 11.10, boot, reboot, bios

I recently update mi Bios Firmware, and when I try lo load up Ubuntu 11.10, it stays halted at a purple screen, it wont even boot. If I then Reboot and go to my Vista Partition, everything is working fine.  In order for Ubuntu 11.10 to boot I need to revert my Bios Firmware to the original.  Why is it so?

Some thing I noticed when flashing the new Bios Firmware is that it changed the time on the Bios, even though I corrected it, it still didn't boot.

I then decided to stay with the original Bios Firmware in order to boot Ubuntu, but I would like to update it. For example, if I reboot my system with the original Bios, it will do everything, but except the act of rebooting itself, it just stays stuck on a blank screen, but powered ON. But with the New Firmware it works great, but not Ubuntu wont boot.

Any help from the community will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what firmware are we talking about? :D

Answer (score 1):

Honestly sounds like a buggy BIOS to me.

They might be changing how the ACPI subsystem works or something with IRQs, or they might have messed around with any other 2-4 letter acronym. It's impossible to say from your question. If they only test for Windows, that might destabilise other systems that rely on things working to a standard.

I suggest you stick with what works best and report a bug to the maker of your motherboard.

If you want to play around, you might want to try appending things like `nomodeset` or `noapic` and [other things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61235/how-grub-setting-noapic-affects-the-system) to the end of your boot string. These basically tell Linux what it can and can't use from the computer so if there is a bug in your motherboard's APIC, you can bypass it.